How can we implement Bluetooth connectivity Permission in .net maui app for windows platform
I'm working on .Net Maui Blazor RFID scanning application. There is required Bluetooth connectivity Permission with RFID Reader device. I have already try multiple code but not compatible with windows platform.
Please provide the source code for window platform. Also let-us know which dependency will be used with .net8.0 compatible.
`using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;

// Check if Bluetooth is supported on the device
bool isBluetoothSupported = await BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorAsync() != null;

if (isBluetoothSupported)
{
    // Request access to Bluetooth
    DeviceAccessStatus accessStatus = await DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceClassAsync(DeviceClass.AllBluetoothDevices).RequestAccessAsync();

    // Check if access is granted
    bool isBluetoothAccessGranted = accessStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed;
    
    if (isBluetoothAccessGranted)
    {
        // Bluetooth access granted, you can proceed with Bluetooth operations
    }
    else
    {
        // Bluetooth access not granted, handle the situation accordingly
    }
}
else
{
    // Bluetooth is not supported on this device
}`

Please compatible .net8.0 supportable code for windows platform
